# How to get data from a ResultSet without explicitly

Tags: java, jdbc, resultset

I'm making a very simple application to display the contents of a database table on a webpage and so I'd like to loop through a ResultSet and stick the contents of each cell between `<td>` tags, etc..

Problem is that the tables can be quite large and I don't want to use the explicit *getString()*, *getInt()*,  *getXXX()* methods.  Instead, it'd be nicer to use the *ResultSetMetaData* method *getColumnType()* as a parameter to a more generic ResultSet `getData(<columName>, <type>)` method, but there doesn't seem to be one.

Is this possible?  Am I going about this the wrong way, or am I way off base?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a getObject() method, but you're still going to have to cast the resulting object unless they're all strings and ints which need no special formatting.  In which case you just check it for null and call toString() if it's valid.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getObject(int)

Comment: imbric can create a wrapper class that takes the getObject() in the constructor and provide a standard getDataString() method to format each of sql types.

Comment: The data is just strings and ints, so that'll work.  Thank you.  It just seems weird that you'd be able to programmatically get at the column type, but not really be able to use that for retrieval in this way.

Comment: @imbric Well, you can always call getString() and get a string representation.  It's just that in a statically-typed language like Java there's not much you can do with the value if you don't know what type it is at compile time.  Sooner or later, somebody either has to cast it so they can use a NumberFormatter or something, or else just call toString() on it.